# why $digest change the 0 numbers to null?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple service

```
return $resource('sampleUrl:url/', {}, {
    create:{method: 'POST', params:{url: 'create'}},
});
```

and have as simple call

```
 $scope.data = {
        x:0,
        y:1
    };

    BranchResourcesStatusService.create($scope.data).$promise.then(function () {
        //success
    }, function () {
        //error
    })
```

unfortunately angular digest just before send data change the 0 numbers to null so the request data will not my object. I need 0 number in the server

[image]

Comment: try `{isArray: true}` in your resource

Comment: @pankajparkar I have tried it but isArray related to server response. in fact I can not construct the my request object . thank you

Comment: Digestion doesn't change values out of the blue. Since `null` is unlikely to come from the UI it's likely set somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days  i was found there were a http interceptor that change the value.
I am so sorry for this question